# CAML query Lookup column value

Tags: caml-query

I have a simple list represent a hierarchy. The list columns: `ID`, `Title`, `Parent`, `other columns`.
Where Parent is a `lookup column` back to the list itself and get information from the Title column.

In a Nintex work flow, I need to look up the parent ID of the current item so to check values of `other columns` in parent item.

The query to get the parent ID, at best, from me is:

```
<Query>
    <Lists>
        <List ID="{8F29198F-04FA-4558-A5A6-64FA8A85E7DE}" />
    </Lists>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Parent" />
    </ViewFields>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            <Value Type="Counter">{WorkflowVariable:CurrentID}</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

When storing the result of the query in a workflow variable `ParentIDLookup`, I, of course only get the parent `Title`, but not the parent `ID`

How do I get the parent `ID` from the current `ID`?

Comment: Note that, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial third-party products. As far as I can tell this is a general SharePoint question which is fine. In future it would be great if you could phrase questions in general terms, rather than in relation to a vendor product (Nintex). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute a CAML query directly on the list ([`SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx)) and not on the site, then you should get a value like `<parentID>;#<parentTitle>` ([SPFielLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx)) for the Parent lookup column.

Comment: Thanks, @Matthias for the answer. However, Nintex does not allow me to do so. As SPDoctor pointed out, it's not appropriate for me to ask this question here. I'll pursue the answer on Nintex site, and hope there is a satisfactory one. Cheers.